# "X consists of elements from Y and just them" - is grammar right?

Tags: grammar

I found the following comment in code:

// Checking that sorted array consists of all elements of the initial array and just them.

Is it correct to use "them" towards abstract objects?
Is grammar generally correct here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. **They, them, their,** and **theirs** can refer to any plural topic. Abstraction and animacy are irrelevant.

On a side note, I would prefer the word **only** to **just**. There is nothing wrong with **just**. My judgment might be subjective here.

Comment: Agree about using `only` but might be even nicer to say `Checking that sorted array consists of all elements of the initial array and *only elements of the initial array*`.